# Returning a certain number of results from the top

Tags: sql, sql-server

***How do I return a certain number of rows, that are a certain number of rows from the top of a SELECT query?***

What I mean is, suppose I had a table with 1000 rows. Suppose I want the first 50 rows, then I want the second 50 rows, then the third 50 rows, and so on. I know that TOP or LIMIT will limit the number of rows that are returned, but I am unsure how to tell SQL to get me the rows from a certain point in the returned table.

Comment: add rowcount filter, but that will only give result from top, like first N records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sql server you can make use of [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function  to do thing you want

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY col3 DESC) AS Row, 
    col1, col2, col3
FROM tablename
```

in short

```
WITH ctetable AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY col3 DESC) AS RowNumber , 
        col1, col2, col3
    FROM tablename 
) 
SELECT * 
FROM ctetable 
WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN 1 AND 50;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 50 * FROM 
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID DESC) AS [Index], * FROM MyTable
) AS A
WHERE A.[Index] BETWEEN @StartIndex AND @EndIndex
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;With CTE as(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (select 0)) AS rno, * FROM MyTable)

select * from CTE where rno between start and end;
```